# HTML Table Stuck

Tags: html, css, html-table

So far, I have got several things going well until my table will not go below my lists.
It is stuck at the top, and when I try and `table { margin-top: 100px}` it moves the table down from the top, but also moves everything below it down, I am wanting it below everything.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML Project</title>
  <style>
    ol {
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 3;
      position: relative;
      opacity: .99;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 200px;
      height: 128px;
    }
    
    ul {
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 3;
      position: relative;
      opacity: .99;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
  </style>
  <div>

    <body>
      <div style="width: 500px; float:left; height:500px; margin:100px">
        <h1>My favorite games</h1>
        <br><br>
        <ol style="float:left">
          <li>Arma 3 - <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARMA_3"> HERE</a></li>
          <br>
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/ArmA_3_Logo_%28Black_Transparent%29_%28SVG%29.svg/1200px-ArmA_3_Logo_%28Black_Transparent%29_%28SVG%29.svg.png" />
          <br>
          <li>World of Tanks - <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Tanks"> HERE</a></li>
          <br>
          <img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/2ef36636-4f93-4e6b-a514-6e14b62670b3/World-of-Tanks-Logo-removebg-preview.png" />
          <br><br>
          <li>Grand Theft Auto V - <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_V"> HERE</a></li>
          <br>
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Acq8WQKCQAEd96M.png" />
          <br>
          <li>Counter Strike: Global Offense - <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive"> HERE</a></li>
          <br>
          <img src="https://www.vippng.com/png/full/62-621853_counter-strike-global-offensive-2-logo-black-and.png" />
          <br><br>
          <li>Digital Combat Simulator World - <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Combat_Simulator"> HERE</a></li>
          <img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/be1dcb6f-0a71-4d4a-a647-553fda3dce23/il_570xN.2519210705_9zed-removebg-preview.png" />
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 500px; float:right; height:500px; margin:100px">
        <h1>My favorite movies</h1>
        <br><br>
        <ul style="float:left">
          <li>Ant-Man - <a href=""> HERE</a></li>
          <br>
          <img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/28ee2a8a-99b6-43f5-b497-9b91da9328c6/s-l640-removebg-preview.png" ; style="width:250px" />
          <br>
          <li>Deadpool - <a href=""> HERE</a></li>
          <br>
          <img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/bb200f2d-93d0-414d-8128-e22bd7849f02/Deadpool-poster-removebg-preview.png" />
          <br><br>
          <li>Jurassic Park - <a href=""> HERE</a></li>
          <br>
          <img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/ac0743ca-d015-41de-8ab5-a2f9c2868850/Jurassic_Park__franchise_logo_-removebg-preview.png" />
          <br>
          <li>Jurassic World - <a href=""> HERE</a></li>
          <br>
          <img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/3473a625-97ec-4eb7-9c7b-be175cb6af2a/jurassicworldlogo-removebg-preview.png" />
          <br><br>
          <li>Curious George - <a href=""> HERE</a></li>
          <img src="https://o.remove.bg/downloads/1ccc478a-eac9-4ec4-a953-44d6a6de704e/Curious-George-Logo-clipart-removebg-preview.png" />
        </ul>
      </div>
      <table>
        <th>
          <td>Game</td>
          <td>Publisher(s)</td>
          <td>Realese Date</td>
          <td>Platform(s)</td>
        </th>
        <tr>
          <td>Arma 3</td>
          <td>Bohemia Interactive</td>
          <td>September 12, 2013</td>
          <td>Microsoft Windows | macOS</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: It's invalid HTML to have a `div` wrapping your `body` tag; the only valid parent of `body` is `html`. The `div` you have above your table is set to `float:left`, which means it will make room for your table on the right. Remove `float:left` if you don't want things to float by it.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to have the table on the very bottom, and the lists next to each other.

Comment: Heretic Monkey, do you have a discord? If so, may I add you, will make it easier to show and explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an issue with positions wrappers I have fixed the issue

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>HTML Project</title>
    <style>
      ol {
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 3;
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0.99;
        list-style-type: none;
      }

      img {
        width: 200px;
        height: 128px;
      }

      ul {
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 3;
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0.99;
        list-style-type: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="display: block; float: left; width: 100%;">
      <div style="width: 500px; float: left; margin: 100px;">
        <h1>My favorite games</h1>
        <br /><br />

        <ol style="float: left;">
          <li>
            Arma 3 - <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARMA_3"> HERE</a>
          </li>
          <br />
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Acq8WQKCQAEd96M.png" />
          <br />
          <li>
            World of Tanks -
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Tanks"> HERE</a>
          </li>
          <br />
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Acq8WQKCQAEd96M.png" />
          <br /><br />
          <li>
            Grand Theft Auto V -
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_V"> HERE</a>
          </li>
          <br />
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Acq8WQKCQAEd96M.png" />
          <br />
          <li>
            Counter Strike: Global Offense -
            <a
              href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive"
            >
              HERE</a
            >
          </li>
          <br />
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Acq8WQKCQAEd96M.png" />
          <br /><br />
          <li>
            Digital Combat Simulator World -
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Combat_Simulator">
              HERE</a
            >
          </li>
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Acq8WQKCQAEd96M.png" />
        </ol>
      </div>

      <div style="width: 500px; float: right; margin: 100px;">
        <h1>My favorite movies</h1>
        <br /><br />
        <ul style="float: left;">
          <li>Ant-Man - <a href=""> HERE</a></li>
          <br />
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Acq8WQKCQAEd96M.png" />
          <br />
          <li>Deadpool - <a href=""> HERE</a></li>
          <br />
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Acq8WQKCQAEd96M.png" />
          <br /><br />
          <li>Jurassic Park - <a href=""> HERE</a></li>
          <br />
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Acq8WQKCQAEd96M.png" />
          <br />
          <li>Jurassic World - <a href=""> HERE</a></li>
          <br />
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Acq8WQKCQAEd96M.png" />
          <br /><br />
          <li>Curious George - <a href=""> HERE</a></li>
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Acq8WQKCQAEd96M.png" />
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: block; float: left; width: 100%;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Game</th>
          <th>Publisher(s)</th>
          <th>Realese Date</th>
          <th>Platform(s)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Arma 3</td>
          <td>Bohemia Interactive</td>
          <td>September 12, 2013</td>
          <td>Microsoft Windows | macOS</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

output can be seen here in full screen: https://4rrmg.csb.app/
with sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-mayer-4rrmg?file=/index.html:0-3450

Comment: This does work, but I wish my links weren't messed with.

Comment: I have repeated the same image, because of broken images.

Comment: Can you please share an image of an expected output .? so that I can help you appropriately.

Comment: Don't just fix the issue, but please tell what the problem was.

Comment: I am unable to share an image on here...

Comment: I just copied part of the code I needed from yours and replaced all of the images, it fixed it. Also, how would I center the table?